# Show the validity of ¬∀x(F x → Gx) ⊢ ∃xFx using natural deduction

Tags: first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I'm very much stuck on this annoying proof, any help would be much appreciated.

I'm assuming I'm using negation elimination on to get the conclusion, and Existential Elimination once I have transformed the premise into ∃x¬(Fx→Gx) - but can't for the life of me figure out how.

Cheers

Comment: $A\to B$ is equivalent to $(\lnot A)\lor B.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

> I'm assuming I'm using negation elimination on to get the conclusion, and Existential Elimination once I have transformed the premise into ∃x¬(Fx→Gx)

Yes, and no.  A *reduction to absurdity* proof is the way to go.  But what existence would you eliminate?

Okay!  To *begin* that proof, you would take the premise and make the assumption you wish to negate.  Depending on your particular proof system, that should look something like this:

$$\fitch{\lnot\forall x~(Fx\to Gx)}{\fitch{\lnot\exists x~Fx}{~\vdots\\\bot}\\\lnot\lnot\exists x~Fx\\\exists x~Fx}$$

Thus: you begin with *two statements* with which you hope to derive a contradiction.  So, you would need to derive either $\exists x~Fx$, or $\forall x~(Fx\to Gx)$.  Obviously, that indicates that *existential introduction* or *universal introduction* could be useful.  But *which*?

Right now, you have nothing extant with which to introduce an existence.  So mayhap you should take an arbitrary term to see if you might derive the conditional statement?

> $$\fitch{\lnot\forall x~(Fx\to Gx)}{\fitch{\lnot\exists x~Fx}{\fitch{\boxed a}{\fitch{Fa}{~\vdots\\Ga}\\ Fa\to Ga}\\\forall x~(Fx\to Gx)\\\bot}\\\lnot\lnot\exists x~Fx\\\exists x~Fx}$$
>
>   That looks promising.  However, how would *you* derive the consequent for that conditional?

You should be able to complete the proof with no further assistance.